# ¿Como crear un cilindro paralelo al eje X con ax.plot_surface?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy intentando hacer un cilindro que contenga a otra figura. Necesitaría saber como podría hacer el cilindro paralelo al eje `X` con la función `ax.plot_surface`. Gracias.

Comment: Coloca tu codigo para que puedan ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Para crear un cilindro paralelo al eje X, con `X` entre `x1` y `x2`, con un radio de `r`, y el eje del cilindro de `x1, y1, z1` hasta `x1, y2, z2`:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = 0
x2 = 10
y1 = 4
z1 = 6
r = 5

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 64)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)

uu, xx = np.meshgrid(u, x)
yy = y1 + r * np.cos(uu)
zz = z1 + r * np.sin(uu)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, color='tomato', alpha=0.7)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

[image: resultado]